# jQuery isn't executing one event, but executes 4 identical ones

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

It's a large layout, so I will just post the parts that are linked to the jQuery and HTML (full site at http://www.gronge.com/index3.php). It all works fine, except the About link changes back to .navBarActive in Firebug inspection but does not visually change. I am new to web design, and this has been my first big issue so far.

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("li.navBarNormal").click(function () {
        $("li.navBarActive").removeClass("navBarActive").addClass("navBarNormal");
        $(this).removeClass("navBarNormal").addClass("navBarActive");
    })
});
```

HTML

```
<ol id="navLinks"> 
    <li id="navLinkAbout" class="liNav fontWhite navBarActive">About</li>
    <li id="navLinkSubscribe" class="liNav fontWhite navBarNormal">Subscribe</li>
    <li id="navLinkNews" class="liNav fontWhite navBarNormal">News</li>
    <li id="navLinkUpdates" class="liNav fontWhite navBarNormal">Updates</li>
    <li id="navLinkContact" class="liNav fontWhite navBarNormal">Contact</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: I would suggest removing the navBarNormal class and simply pass the "Active" class to the current item.  Then bind the click event to all the ListItems.  That way you are not messing with the class you are using in the selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are not setting the event listener on the `#navLinkAbout` node, as this node does not have a `navBarNormal` class to start with.

My suggestion is to use a better selector for setting the listener, like `#navLinks li`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#navLinks li").click(function () {
        $("li.navBarActive").removeClass("navBarActive").addClass("navBarNormal");
        $(this).removeClass("navBarNormal").addClass("navBarActive");
    })
});
```

Comment: You my friend, are the greatest!

Answer (score 1):

try this: http://jsfiddle.net/treyeckels/DgQfw/

Change the event trigger to "li.liNav". That will apply the event handler to all the links. Then do your add/remove action on this (that which was clicked), traverse and find the siblings and do their add/remove actions.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("li.liNav").click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("navBarNormal").addClass("navBarActive").siblings().removeClass("navBarActive").addClass("navBarNormal");
}) });​
```